# Test for convergence of integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Considering the behaviour of the integrant at both integration limits, study the convergence
of the integral:

$$\int_{0}^\infty x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^\frac{3}{2}}\right). $$

I was trying to integrate it but I don't know if that is even possible and also to use some comparison test but it wasn't really helpful.

I know that I can rewrite it as:

$$\int_{0}^c x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^\frac{3}{2}}\right) + \int_{c}^\infty x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$
 where $c$ is some positive number, but I don't know what to do next.

How should I test the convergence of that integral?

Comment: this integral does not converge on the given interval

Answer (score 0):

As $\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x}=1$,$\;x\to\infty\implies x\sin(x^{-1.5})\to x\cdot x^{-1.5}=x^{-0.5}$.
If $c>0,$ $\int_c^\infty x^{-p}\,dx<\infty\iff p>1.$ So the $2$nd integral doesn't converge. As  $|x\sin(x^{-1.5})|\le |x|$ and $\int_0^c|x|dx=0.5c^2,$ the $1$st integral converges. So the integral $\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^{-1.5})$ doesn't converge.